# How to make mutual recursion in APL?

Tags: recursion, logical-operators, apl, mutual-recursion, dyalog

I'm trying the following mutual recursion example in [Dyalog](https://www.dyalog.com/) APL Win10:

```
      even ← { (odd  ⍵-1) ∨ ⍵=0 }
      odd  ← { (even ⍵-1) ∧ ⍵>0 }
      even 7
WS FULL
```

It looks like the `∨` and `∧` doesn't stop evaluation at reaching a defined state.
The WS FULL shows that the recursion actually works but doesn't terminate properly.

How to make mutual recursion in APL?

PS.
I'm very new to APL and doesn't know the proper syntax of `∇` functions. Anyway, I prefer a more "functional" style, if it is possible.

Comment: `∧` and `∨` are normal functions, not short-circuiting.

Comment: Ooo, I see. They evaluate both arguments. `∨` `∧` are not "special forms" and cannot do it.

Comment: I've amended my answer to include usage of short-circuiting operators.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `∧` and `∨` are normal functions, and do not short-circuit, you have to use "guards" instead:

```
      even ← {⍵=0:1 ⋄ odd ⍵-1}
      odd  ← {⍵>0:even ⍵-1 ⋄ 0}
      even 7
0
```

Alternatively, you can define your own short-circuiting operators. You can find ready-made definitions [on APLcart](https://aplcart.info?q=short-circuit):

```
      OR   ← {⍺⍺ ⍵:1 ⋄ ⍵⍵ ⍵}
      AND  ← {⍺⍺ ⍵:⍵⍵ ⍵ ⋄ 0}
      even ← {=∘0 OR  (odd  -∘1) ⍵}
      odd  ← {>∘0 AND (even -∘1) ⍵}
      even 7
0
```